# tables-package: How to output factor levels in latex math mode?

Tags: r, latex

I want to generate a latex table from within R using the tables package. My problem is that I would like to directly use names for the factor levels that can be displayed in latex math mode. Here is an example:

```
library("tables")
df <- data.frame(Factor = c("A", "B"), value = c(1, 2))
levels(df$Factor) <- c("$x^2$", "$n_p$")
latex(tabular(table = Heading("$F_c$") * Factor ~ value * identity,data = df))
```

I get the output:

```
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{value} \\ 
$F_c$  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{identity} \\ 
\midrule
\$x$^{2}$\$  & $1$ \\
\$n\_p\$  & $2$ \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
```

However, I want to get $x^2$ and $n_p$ in the output, and not \$x$^{2}$\$ and \$n_p\$. I can't understand why it is working for the column names, but not for the names of the factor levels.

Comment: The `x^2` you could get without `$`. But not `n_p`.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, I noticed that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xtable instead:

```
library("xtable")
df <- data.frame(Factor = c("A", "B"), value = c(1, 2))
levels(df$Factor) <- c("$x^2$", "$n_p$")
tab<-xtable(df)
print(tab,sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x})
```

This gives the following output:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.2.2 by xtable 1.8-0 package
% Fri Dec  4 11:47:22 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlr}
  \hline
 & Factor & value \\ 
  \hline
1 & $x^2$ & 1.00 \\ 
  2 & $n_p$ & 2.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

HTH!